# Message not received from Python to Android with socket

Tags: android, python, sockets, client-server

my android application needs to communicate with a server python but at the time to receive a response, the answer does not come. These are my codes:

This is my Client:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 5589;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.131";
TextView risp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    risp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

public void onClick(View view) {
    try {
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
        out.println(str);
        out.flush();

        // Read from sock
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                socket.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
        }
        risp.setText(risp.getText().toString() + " " + response.toString());
        out.close();
        input.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

And this is the Server:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('192.168.1.131', 5589)
print >>sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address
sock.bind(server_address)
# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

while True:
        # Wait for a connection
        print >>sys.stderr, 'waiting for a connection'
        connection, client_address = sock.accept()
        try:
                print >>sys.stderr, 'connection from', client_address

                # Receive the data
                while True:
                        data = connection.recv(1024)
                        if data.lower() != 'q':
                                print "<-- client: ", data
                        else:
                                print "Quit from Client"
                                connection.close()
                                break
                        data = raw_input("--> server: ")
                        if data.lower() != 'q':
                                connection.sendall(data)
                        else:
                                print "Quit from Server"
                                connection.close()
                                break

        finally:
                # Clean up the connection
                print "Connection close"
                connection.close()
```

The server receive the client message, but the client doesn't receive the server message. Why?

Thanks all in advance

EDIT: I SOLVED it this way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket socket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 5589;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.131";
    TextView risp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        risp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        new ConnectionTask().execute();
    }

    class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String responce = null;
            try {
                EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                String str = et.getText().toString();
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                out.println(str);
                out.flush();

                InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
                int lockSeconds = 10*1000;

                long lockThreadCheckpoint = System.currentTimeMillis();
                int availableBytes = input.available();
                while(availableBytes <=0 && (System.currentTimeMillis() < lockThreadCheckpoint + lockSeconds)){
                    try{Thread.sleep(10);}catch(InterruptedException ie){ie.printStackTrace();}
                    availableBytes = input.available();
                }

                byte[] buffer = new byte[availableBytes];
                input.read(buffer, 0, availableBytes);
                responce = new String(buffer);

                out.close();
                input.close();
                socket.close();
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responce;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String responce) {
            risp.setText(responce);
        }
    }

    class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your client is trying to read lines. But is your server sending them?

Comment: I added the log. However, the server sends its response, it is the client who can not receive it / read it. I tried the server with a client.py and it works, then the problem should be or the client, or the way in which the server send the answer (perhaps with the java procedure is different).
Or the problem may be that the getInputStream() is not blocking..

Comment: Please reread what i said and react to the point. Is your server sending lines? As your client will hang if it does not.

Comment: As I understand, as you said the program crashes in input.readLine(). But my server sends the response, so I do not understand what the problem is.
I also tried to automatically send from server a standard response, but nothing changes.

Comment: I did not say that the program crashes in readLine. But why are you not telling if the server sends lines? I already asked that two times. Now for the third time!

Comment: Sorry, I explained badly, my english is not very good. 
My server send the line! When run "data = raw_input (" -> server: ")" I write "hello" in my terminal and I press enter.
This caused no problem in my test client.py and server.py

Comment: 'Hello' is a word. If the server only sends 'Hello' than that is no line and the client will hang. The server should send 'Hello\n' to let it be a line. So what does the server send exactly?

Comment: In the previous version of the code I tried to send from the server also "sendall (data+"\n")" but unfortunately I have not solved.
In this version of the code can also simply send a "word" and everything works perfectly. Thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: I just had the same problem. I'm searching for it like 2 day but couldn't fix this until i saw this page. Your code worked fine for me. Thanks alot.